# PACT: How to guard against consumer generating incorrect contracts

Tags: pact

We have two micro-services: Provider and Consumer, both are built independently. Consumer micro-service makes a mistake in how it consumes Provider service (for whatever reason) and as a result, incorrect pact is published to the Pact Broker.
Consumer service build is successful (and can go all the way to release!), but next Provider service build will fail for the wrong reason. So we end up with the broken Provider service build and a broken release of Consumer.

What is the best practice to guard against situations like this?

I was hoping that Pact Broker can trigger the Provider tests automatically when contracts are published and notify Consumers if they fail, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the nature of *consumer*-driven contracts - the consumer gets a significant say in the API!

As a general rule, if the contract doesn't change, there is no need to run the Provider build, albeit there is currently no easy way to know this in the Broker (see feature request https://github.com/bethesque/pact_broker/issues/48).

As for solutions you could use one or more of the below strategies.

**Effective use of code branches**

It is of course very important that new assumptions on the contract be validated by the Provider before the Consumer can be safely released. Have branches tested against the Provider before you merge into master.

But most importantly - you *must* be collaborating closely with the Provider team!

**Use source control to detect a modified contract:**

If you also checked the master pact files into source control, your CI build could conditionally act - if the contract has changed, you must wait for a green provider build, if not you can safely deploy!

**Store in separate repository**

If you really want the provider to maintain control, you could store contracts in an intermediate repository or file location managed by the provider. I'd recommend this is a last resort as it negates much of the collaboration pact intends to facilitate.

**Use Pact Broker Webhooks:**

> I  was hoping that Pact Broker can trigger the Provider tests automatically when contracts are published and notify Consumers if they fail, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Yes, this is possible using [web hooks](https://github.com/bethesque/pact_broker/blob/master/lib/pact_broker/doc/views/webhooks.markdown) on the Pact Broker. You could trigger a build on the Provider as soon as a new contract is submitted to the server.

You could envisage this step working with options 1 and 2.

See [Using Pact where the Consumer team is different from the Provider team](https://docs.pact.io/faq/#using-pact-where-the-consumer-team-is-different-from-the-provider-team) in our FAQ for more on this use case.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed advice and a few fresh ideas. I like the idea to run provider tests as part of the consumer pipeline. To achieve this we likely will need to include provider tests into the provider Docker image and have a way to trigger the tests.

Comment: No worries! Just be careful, you want to avoid always having to run the Provider build after each consumer build - independently releasable components is what we want after all. Ideally, focus only on the case where the contract changes.

Answer (score 0):

You're spot on, that is one of the current things lacking with the Pact workflow and it's something I've been meaning of working towards once a few other things align.

That being said, in the meantime, this isn't solving your current problem, so I'm going to suggest a potential workaround in your process.  Instead of running the test for the consumer, them passing, and then releasing it straight away, you could have the test run on the consumer, then wait for the provider test to come back green before releasing the consumer/provider together.  Another way would be to version your provider/consumer interactions (api versioning) so that you can release the consumer beforehand, but isn't "turned on" until the correct version of the provider is released.

None of these solutions are great and I wholeheartedly agree.  This is something that I'm quite passionate about and will be working on soon to fix the developer experience with pact broker and releasing the consumer/provider in a better fashion.

Any and all comments are welcome.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good to know you have this planned!

Comment: @YuriSokolovski Definitely, would love to know more about your current workflow though.  Please send me a message/email through my profile if you have a spare 5 minutes.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be caused by the fact that contracts are generated on the consumer side. It means that consumers can modify those contracts how they want. But in the end producer's build will suffer due to incorrect contracts generated by consumers.
Is there any way that contracts are defined by producer? As I think the producer is responsible for maintaining its own contracts. For instance, in case of Spring Cloud Contracts it is recommended to have contacts defined in producer sources (e.g. in the same git repo with producer source code) or in a separate scm repo that can be managed by producer and consumer together.

Comment: You're right.  In our last Pact meeting with the foundation members, we've talked about how to change this from a 'consumer driven contract' to a 'collaboration driven contract' so that input from both the consumer and the provider can go both ways.  More on this soon :)

Comment: You could always store the contracts in a separate repo/location managed by the provider team. I'll add this to my answer

Comment: Thanks @MatthewFellows for the comment. Actually I did this already. And it is much better. So now I have several Junit tests in a separate git repository with State annotations that describe how to switch provider to a specific state (FYI provider is run as docker container using docker-compose-rule). And I run those test to verify producer against contracts.

But contracts themselves are still defined in consumer's integration tests using Pact annotations. I would like to have ability to have those contracts separately from integration test in my contracts git repository.

Comment: OK I understand. As J_A_X noted this is something not yet available but looking into